# Displaying multiple content dynamically using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am adding content to a div using jquery based on a drop down menu.  The user selects an item and it is added as a `<p>` element.

The drop down is multi select so the value of it can be multiple items.

My code is:

```
    $('#dataCombo').on('change', function () {
    var selectedData = $("#dataCombo").val().toString();   //get the selected options
     $('#displayData').replaceWith("<p>"+ selectedData + "</p>"); //add to div
     console.log(selectedData );
});
```

The `console.log` works fine, it shows the data i expect, but the div only shows the one item (the first selected data).

I thought by using `replaceWith` instead of append it would re-render all the months but no luck.  When i use append it shows all selected items, but incorrectly (repeats on each line so: `data1, data1 data2, data1 data2 data3`
Instead of: `data1, data2, data3`

Any ideas how i achieve this?  The drop downs use bootstrap for the css/js multi select functionality.

Here's the updated jQuery fiddle not quite working:
http://jsfiddle.net/vLAcj/1

Comment: Could you create a JsFiddle with your HTML code please ? @Hagbard

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vLAcj/

Comment: The fiddle above works as i want it to barring one thing - i'm wanting to append a X on the end of each item so:
http://jsfiddle.net/vLAcj/1/
But as you can see it just adds the X onto the second item.  I need the X so i can use it to remove the item through jQuery at a later date.
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using .replaceWith? This will replace your #displayData div with the new p tag. Maybe this causes some problem? I think you might want to use .html instead. Like so:

```
$('#displayData').html("<p>"+ selectedData + "</p>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct way is

```
$('#displayData').html("<p>"+ selectedData + "</p>");
```

Try this out.
Example http://jsfiddle.net/nGP6L/2/

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to used "append":

```
$( "#displayData" ).append( "<p>"+ selectedData + "</p>" );
```

Comment: If you want to use append you need to clear the div before appending otherwise you would keep appending items for each change event.